# in C#, How to save a struct to MongoDB (as easily as I save an instance of a class)?

Tags: c#, mongodb, value-type

I understand that there is a problem with saving value types. This means that logging structs might be a problem with MongoDB.

What is the best way to save a struct into a MongoDB then?

Comment: Two remarks: *saving* is easy - it will work by default. Reading, however, is not. You'd either need to write a custom deserializer, or use a generic struct deserializer which is provided in the dupe. This problem still exists with 2.0-beta2 driver. The Jira ticket is at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-94